# Display clipboard (paste) onLongPress without showing the keyboard

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on react-native application, I would like to be able to show the clipboard onLongPress in TextInput without showing the keyboard. 
The keyboard should only display if the user shortpress (tap).

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={true}>
         <TextInput
               placeholder={props.messages.placeholder.token}
               keyboardType={"default"}
               onChangeText={(text) => props.setControlToken({ text })}
               underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
               style={{
                   borderBottomWidth: 1,
                   borderRadius: 4,
                   fontSize: inputFontSize
              }}
          />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Thanks